# Getting latest tag from git (on all branches) in gradle

Tags: android, git, gradle

I'm trying to get the latest tag from git (from all branches) for versioning. I use the following:

```
def sout = new StringBuilder(),
    serr = new StringBuilder()
def proc = 'git describe --tags $(git rev-list, --tags --max-count=1)'.execute()
proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
proc.waitForOrKill(1000)
println "out> $sout\nerr> $serr"
```

However I get the error that `error: unknown option max-count=1)`, it works in the terminal, how do I get this to work in groovy?

Comment: It's probably better so use for example JGit or the grgit Gradle plugin to get information from Git as those are Java implementations of Git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1)` involves two separate commands - `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1` and `git describe --tags <some-revision>`. When it is executed in the terminal, the shell used in the terminal executes the `git rev-list` command first, substitutes its output into the `git describe` command and then executes it. An equivalent one-liner in groovy would look something like `['sh', '-c', 'git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1)'].execute()`. But if a one-liner is not strictly required, removing the nesting and executing the `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1` command separately and then using its output in the `git describe --tags` command worked for me. The final code looked like the below:

```
String revision = 'git rev-list --tags --max-count=1'.execute().text
def sout = new StringBuilder(),
    serr = new StringBuilder()
def proc = "git describe --tags ${revision}".execute()
proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
proc.waitForOrKill(1000)
println "out> $sout\nerr> $serr"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate commands:

```bash
git tag --sort=-authordate |head -1
```

Add `--merged` to limit to tags in the current branch's history:

```bash
git tag --sort=-authordate --merged |head -1
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you try to access git is absolutely not idiomatic for Gradle. For an approach like that you are probably better off writing a bash script.

That said, if you want to access git from Gradle in a way that is compatible with latest features like configuration cache and cacheable to avoid rerunning it every time you sync your Gradle build there is a way to achieve that.

But before, I would like to explain you the value of actually making your Gradle build cacheable.

Each time you sync your Gradle project, no matter if you press sync Gradle button, Play button in IDE or sync your Gradle project from command line, Gradle ALWAYS performs the configuration phase before executing required tasks. So your script will execute EVERY single time you sync your project. I doubt this is actually what you are trying to achieve.

To make sure there is no work that was not required you have to create a task with properly declared inputs and outputs. Whether to create a standalone task by extending `DefaultTask` class or go for ad hoc implementation is up to you but you have to use APIs that allow for lazy evaluation like `providers.exec {}`

```
val output = providers.exec { commandLine("git", "describe", "--tags") }
.standardOutput
.asText.get().trim().split('-').first()
```

Defining your external process like this inside a task will allow you to avoid executing your logic when it's not required.

More info: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:configuration